# Showing that something is a maximal ideal of the ring of fractions.

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose R is an integral domain and P is a prime ideal of R (i.e. P is in the spectrum of R).  Set S = R$\setminus$P.  Then S is a multiplicatively closed subset of R that contains no zero-divisors.  Show that:

PS$^{-1}$ (where P is a prime ideal) is a maximal ideal of the fraction ring RS$^{-1}$.

Attempt:

I know that (using the def'n of maximal ideal) I must assume there is some maximal ideal "M" of RS$^{-1}$ that contains PS$^{-1}$ and then show that M must in fact be equal to PS$^{-1}$.

Suppose M = NS$^{-1}$, where N properly contains P.  If I focus only on N, which is a subset of R, and show that N is an ideal of R that contains P then maybe I can force it to be equal to P.  I'm not sure if this would work.  I tried playing around with this idea but didn't make much headway.

Is this right or is there something else I should be trying?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: You're in the right track. Not only is $\;PS^{-1}=:pR_P\;$  a maximal ideal of $\;RS^{-1}=:R_P\;$ , but in fact **the only** maximal ideal of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n/s \in NS^{-1}$. If $n \not\in P$, then $n \in S$ by definition of $S$. Hence, $1 = s/n \cdot n/s \in NS^{-1}$, therefore $NS^{-1} = RS^{-1}$. So $PS^{-1}$ is maximal.